# Use model in Razor view from another project in mvc ASP.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two projects in one space which are user and admin. I am trying to access data model from admin in user views. I have added the references but it is still not letting me use it.

Comment: Have you added a reference to the other project within the project you're trying to access it's data model? 

Is the data model public?

Can you please share some code as to how you're trying to use the data model?

Comment: Yes, I have added the references and the y are public as well

Comment: What is your compile time error?